# Splitting a binary file with 0xff stuffing

Tags: linux, perl, file, split, binary

I would like to split a binary file into subfiles named with a prefix followed by a decimal offset like `prefix-3200.bin, prefix-3201.bin`.

I found that I can split my file with

```
split -b128k -d input.bin
```

which generates files named x00, x01, x02, ...

Unfortunately I still need to translate the blocks names and fill the last block with 0xff because all my blocks should have the same size of 128kB.

I'm thinking to use Perl to do the job but it would be much better if I can only use standard GNU tools.

How I can easily rename and pad my last binary block ?

I tried to use dd with this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero ibs=1k count=128 | tr "\000" "\377" > block
dd if=block of=block conv=notrunc
```

**Edit:**

I can now generates the correct `prefix-XXXX` with

```
split -b128k -d -a4 input.bin prefix-
```

Comment: [`rename`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/rename.html) and `$buf = substr($buf . ("\xFF" x (128*1024)), 0, 128*1024);`

Comment: Also, `split` takes the prefix as the last argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $block_size = 128*1024;

open(my $fh_in, '<:raw', 'input.bin') or die $!;

local $/ = \$block_size;
my $counter = 0;
while (<$fh_in>) {
   open(my $fh_out, '>:raw', sprintf("prefix-%04d.bin", $counter++)) or die $!;
   $_ = substr($_.("\xFF" x $block_size), 0, $block_size);
   print($fh_out $_);
}
```

Comment: Most people can see that this is perl.
Why is this better than using `split` or at least why should I use it?

Comment: @wojciii, Because `split` doesn't do the the OP needs.

Answer (score 1):

Having GNU split, you can use the following `split` command:

```
split -b128k --additional-suffix=".bin" -a4 --numeric-suffixes=3200 INPUT_FILE "prefix-"
```

However, you would need to explicitly fill the last file with `0xFF`s afterwards. You might use `dd` for that, as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/274972/how-to-pad-a-file-with-ff-using-dd)

Comment: Saddly, I don't have the option `--additional-suffix` with my split 8.15

Comment: Ah, ok. Good to know that this isn't portable. Will explicitly add `GNU split` to my answer.